# Cannot connect to ArangoDB Server

Tags: c#, arangodb

I Have a Simple form where i want to connect to any database present in arangoDB interface. I am using this code on form load event provided by the documentation but i am unable to understand the documentation.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            ArangoDatabase.ChangeSetting(s =>
            {
                s.Database = "TutorialDotNet";
                s.Url = "http://localhost:8529";
               
                // you can set other settings if you need
                s.Credential = new NetworkCredential("root", "6421515");
                s.SystemDatabaseCredential = new NetworkCredential("root", "6421515");
            });
            
        }
```

I have a button where i am checking the database info like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (var db = ArangoDatabase.CreateWithSetting())
            {

                db.CreateDatabase("TutorialDotNet");

                var currentDatabaseInfo = db.CurrentDatabaseInformation();

                // path of the created database
                MessageBox.Show(currentDatabaseInfo.Path);
            }
        }
```

on cliking the button i get this error
[image]
Plz help me with this thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/ra0o0f/arangoclient.net

Comment: Sorry for being a little bit inappropriate regarding the documentation. If you read the documentation and if you are able to find a way to connect to the database and perform any action plz help me with that I'm in the middle of some project.

Comment: It sounds like the user might be invalid. I will say this though: that repository hasn't been touched in 2+ years (other than the readme being updated). The ArangoDB site link is broken (CloudFlare can't find it). Are you sure you want to be using a database engine that is seemingly no longer maintained?

Comment: That is my bad choice....which engine you would suggest my sir?

Comment: Apologies, it seems like that is just that specific client driver for the database, and that there are other .NET clients. You can see .NET drivers on the [official site](https://www.arangodb.com/download/drivers/). [This one](https://github.com/Actify-Inc/arangodb-net-standard) appears to be the one with the most recent activity. I would suggest trying to use that one instead.

Comment: Thanks For your valuable suggestion. I would get back to the hustle though. with a suggested driver or any other.